# Unable to install Angularjs on Windows 7

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git

While installing angularjs on windows 7. It fails with the below message:

```
C:\angular.js>npm install
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 ced17cbe52c1412b2ada53160432a5b681f37cd7: fatal: bad o
bject ced17cbe52c1412b2ada53160432a5b681f37cd7
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 ced17cbe52c1412b2ada53160432a5b681f37cd7:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-
cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true rev-list -n1 ced17cbe52c1412
b2ada53160432a5b681f37cd7
npm ERR! fatal: bad object ced17cbe52c1412b2ada53160432a5b681f37cd7
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\angular.js\npm-debug.log
```

What is the reason for fatal bad object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing angular with NPM inside the console window in an IDE like webstorm for example, you can try installing it with your powershell for example, i think that should solve this error.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried with Powershell there is no change same error message. 

npm debug.log file contains the below( few lines)
3357 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/dgeni-packages from cache
3361 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\002812\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\dgeni-packages\0.10.17\package\package.json written
3362 verbose stack Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true rev-list -n1 ced17cbe52c1412b2ada53160432a5b681f37cd7
3362 verbose stack fatal: bad object ced17cbe52c1412b2ada53160432a5b681f37cd7

Comment: Does your git still work outside your application? (you can test that by doing an git init in an different folder)

Comment: Yes git is working fine
C:\angular.js>git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/angular.js/.git/

Comment: Resolved!
Issue was with devDependencies "grunt-jasmine-node" mentioned in angularjs package.json file. 
Changed it from "grunt-jasmine-node": "git://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-jasmine-node.git#fix-grunt-exit-code"
to "grunt-jasmine-node": "~2.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

Issue was with devDependencies "grunt-jasmine-node" mentioned in angularjs package.json file.

Changed it from "grunt-jasmine-node": "git://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-jasmine-node.git#fix-grunt-exit-code" to "grunt-jasmine-node": "~2.0.1"

grunt-jasmine-node was the referring to the fatal object